# How to display only information about the graph on which the mouse is hovered over in a tooltip when the mode is Index in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, hover, tooltip

I am currently drawing a line chart using chart.js.
In the footer of the tooltip, we added `Chart.defaults.plugins.tooltip.mode = "index";` to display the added value based on the index. However, after adding the sentence, all values ​​of the index will be displayed in the tooltip as shown in the picture below. I need the total value, but I want the tooltip to only display information about the graph I hovered over. Please help.

Additionally, when I hover over one graph, I also need to adjust the opacity values ​​of the remaining graphs. If anyone knows, please help.

[current screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtCyA.png)

```
"use client";

import { Chart, TooltipItem } from "chart.js/auto";
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";

Chart.register();

const footer = (tooltipItems: TooltipItem<"line">[]) => {
  let sum = 0;

  tooltipItems.forEach(function (tooltipItem) {
    sum += tooltipItem.parsed.y;
  });

  return "total count: " + sum;
};

const Test = () => {
  return (
    <Line
      style={{ maxHeight: "280px", maxWidth: "1200px" }}
      data={{
        labels: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        datasets: [
          { label: "label1", data: [10, 16, 4, 20, 10, 30, 5, 9, 31] },
          { label: "label2", data: [40, 4, 10, 13, 20, 21, 9, 23, 7] },
        ],
      }}
      options={{
        plugins: {
          tooltip: {
            callbacks: {
              footer: footer,
            },
          },
        },
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default Test;

Chart.defaults.plugins.tooltip.caretPadding = 12;
Chart.defaults.plugins.tooltip.caretPadding = 12;
Chart.defaults.plugins.tooltip.intersect = false;
Chart.defaults.plugins.tooltip.mode = "index";
Chart.defaults.plugins.tooltip.position = "nearest";
Chart.defaults.plugins.tooltip.displayColors = false;
Chart.defaults.plugins.tooltip.titleFont = { size: 0 };
Chart.defaults.plugins.tooltip.footerFont = { weight: "500" };
Chart.defaults.plugins.tooltip.usePointStyle = true;
Chart.defaults.elements.line.borderWidth = 2;
Chart.defaults.datasets.line.pointStyle = false;
```